# pinescript Code error: the code compiles but has an error when added to indicator window

Tags: debugging, pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

Good day guys, I wrote this code that plots peak using hi, lo and close of two time frames. The code successfully compiled on pine editor but on the indicator window in trading view it keeps giving me an error. I have tried adjusting multiple things but the error still persists. I need someone to help debug the code. I have two versions of the code, the difference between both is that for the first one I used arrays, while for the other code I used matrix. Thanks in advance.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © felixxzz

//@version=5
indicator("Custom Indicator", overlay=false, max_bars_back = 1000)
import TradingView/ta/5
import mentalRock19315/NumberOfVisibleBars/3



len = input.int(15, title="Len")
historyBars = input.int(500, title="HistoryBars")


tf1 =input.timeframe("", "Tf1")
tf2 = input.timeframe("", "Tf2")

var float[] UP = array.new_float()
var float[] DN = array.new_float()
var float Clos = na
var float Hig = na
var float Loww = na
var int curBarIndex = na
var int barssCounter = na
var float Highest = na
var float Lowest = na
var float sumUpward = na 
var float sumDownward = na
var float sumHigh = na
var float sumLow = na
var int barSinceSignal = na


historyBars := math.round(historyBars / (time(tf2) / time(timeframe.period)))


// generate values from 0 to historybars+len

var ArrayClose = array.new<float>()
var ArrayLo = array.new<float>()
var ArrayHi = array.new<float>()

array.push(ArrayClose, historyBars + len)
array.push(ArrayHi, historyBars + len)
array.push(ArrayLo, historyBars + len)

barSinceSignal_value(index) =>
    ta.barssince(time(tf1)== request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tf2,index))

barSinceSignal_value1(a) =>
    (barSinceSignal_value(a) - time(tf2)) + 1

barsinTf2_value(index) =>
    ta.barssince(time(timeframe.period)== request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tf2,index))

barsinTf2_value1(index) =>
   
    barsinTf2_value(index) - time(tf2)/time(timeframe.period)


BSSV = barSinceSignal_value(historyBars + len)
BSSV1 = barSinceSignal_value1(historyBars + len)

BITV =  barsinTf2_value(historyBars)
BITV1= barsinTf2_value1(historyBars)

closedValue(j) =>
    closed_value = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1,close [j])
        
highValue(j) => 
    high_value = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1,high[j])

lowValue(j) =>
    low_value = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1,low[j])
        
HiLOCloValue(index) =>
    closedValue(index)
    highValue(index)
    lowValue(index)


ArrayResize(index) =>
    cnt =0
    for i = (index) -  1 to 1
        for j = BSSV to BSSV1 by 1
            array.set(ArrayClose, i,HiLOCloValue(j))
            array.set(ArrayHi, i, HiLOCloValue(j))
            array.set(ArrayHi, i, HiLOCloValue(j))
            
    cnt :=cnt + 1



ArrayResize(historyBars + len)

for i = historyBars to 1
    max_bars_back(barssCounter, 5000) 
    barssCounter := 0
    sumUpward := 0
    sumDownward := 0
    Highest := 0
    Lowest := 1000000
    if barssCounter < len
        curBarIndex := i + barssCounter 
        sumHigh := 0
        sumLow := 0
           
        for  k = 0 to  (time(tf2))
            if array.get(ArrayClose,curBarIndex[k])  > 0.0
                Clos := array.get(ArrayClose,curBarIndex[k]) 
            if array.get(ArrayHi,curBarIndex[k]) > 0.0
                Hig := array.get(ArrayHi,curBarIndex[k])
            if array.get(ArrayLo,curBarIndex[k]) > 0.0
                Loww := array.get(ArrayLo,curBarIndex[k])
            if (Hig > Highest)
                Highest := Hig
                sumHigh := sumHigh + Clos
            if (Loww < Lowest)
                Lowest := Loww
                sumLow := sumLow + Clos
            else 
                break
             

        if (sumHigh > 0.0)
            sumUpward += sumHigh
        if (sumLow > 0.0)
            sumDownward += sumLow
        barssCounter := barssCounter + 1
    else
        break


if (sumUpward > 0.0 and sumDownward > 0.0)
    
    for  barsCounter2 = BITV to BITV1
        array.set(UP, barsCounter2, sumUpward / sumDownward)
        array.set(DN, barsCounter2, sumDownward / sumUpward)
        

UP_value = array.get(UP, 1)
DN_value = array.get(DN, 1)
 

plot(UP_value, "Label1", color=color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(DN_value, "Label2", color=color.red, linewidth=1)
```

for the second code

```
indicator("Custom Indicator", overlay=false, max_bars_back = 5000)
import TradingView/ta/5
import mentalRock19315/NumberOfVisibleBars/3



len = input.int(15, title="Len")
historyBars = input.int(2345, title="HistoryBars")


tf1 =input.timeframe("", "Tf1")
tf2 = input.timeframe("", "Tf2")

var float[] UP = array.new_float()
var float[] DN = array.new_float()
var float Clos = na
var float Hig = na
var float Loww = na
var int curBarIndex = na
var int barssCounter = na
var float Highest = na
var float Lowest = na
var float sumUpward = na 
var float sumDownward = na
var float sumHigh = na
var float sumLow = na
var int barSinceSignal = na


historyBars := math.round(historyBars / (time(tf2) / time(timeframe.period)))


// generate values from 0 to historybars+len

var ArrayClose = matrix.new<float>(historyBars + len ,10,historyBars + len)
var ArrayLo = matrix.new<float>(historyBars + len,10,historyBars + len)
var ArrayHi = matrix.new<float>(historyBars + len,10,historyBars + len)


barSinceSignal_value(index) =>
    ta.barssince(time(tf1)== request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tf2,index))

barSinceSignal_value1(a) =>
    (barSinceSignal_value(a) - time(tf2)) + 1

barsinTf2_value(index) =>
    ta.barssince(time(timeframe.period)== request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tf2,index))

barsinTf2_value1(index) =>
   
    barsinTf2_value(index) - time(tf2)/time(timeframe.period)


BSSV = barSinceSignal_value(historyBars + len)
BSSV1 = barSinceSignal_value1(historyBars + len)

BITV =  barsinTf2_value(historyBars)
BITV1= barsinTf2_value1(historyBars)

closedValue(j) =>
    closed_value = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1,close [j])
        
highValue(j) => 
    high_value = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1,high[j])

lowValue(j) =>
    low_value = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1,low[j])
        
HiLOCloValue(index) =>
    closedValue(index)
    highValue(index)
    lowValue(index)

ArrayResize(index) =>
    cnt = 0
    for i = (index) -  1 to 1
        for j = BSSV to BSSV1 by 1
            matrix.set(ArrayClose,i, i,HiLOCloValue(j))
            matrix.set(ArrayHi, i,i, HiLOCloValue(j))
            matrix.set(ArrayHi, i,i, HiLOCloValue(j))
            
    cnt :=cnt + 1



ArrayResize(historyBars + len)

for i = historyBars to 1
    barssCounter := 0
    sumUpward := 0
    sumDownward := 0
    Highest := 0
    Lowest := 1000000
    if barssCounter < len
        curBarIndex := i + barssCounter
        sumHigh := 0
        sumLow := 0
           
        for  k = 0 to  (time(tf2) - 1)
            if matrix.get(ArrayClose,curBarIndex,k) > 0.0
                Clos := matrix.get(ArrayClose,curBarIndex,k)
            if matrix.get(ArrayHi,curBarIndex,k) > 0.0
                Hig := matrix.get(ArrayHi,curBarIndex,k)
            if matrix.get(ArrayHi,curBarIndex,k) > 0.0
                Loww := matrix.get(ArrayHi,curBarIndex,k)

            if (Hig > Highest)
                Highest := Hig
                sumHigh := sumHigh + Clos
            if (Loww < Lowest)
                Lowest := Loww
                sumLow := sumLow + Clos
            
        if (sumHigh > 0.0)
            sumUpward += sumHigh
        if (sumLow > 0.0)
            sumDownward += sumLow
        barssCounter := barssCounter + 1
    else
        break


if (sumUpward > 0.0 and sumDownward > 0.0)
    
    for  barsCounter2 = BITV to BITV1
        array.set(UP, barsCounter2, sumUpward / sumDownward)
        array.set(DN, barsCounter2, sumDownward / sumUpward)
        

UP_value = array.get(UP, 0)
DN_value = array.get(DN, 0)
 

plot(UP_value, "Label1", color=color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(DN_value, "Label2", color=color.red, linewidth=1)
```

I have tweaked the code to the best of my knowledge but it seems it's beyond me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: For the first code, " Error on bar 0: in the array.get function,.index 500 is out of bound, array size is 1" while for the second code it gives similar error " Error in bar 0: in the matrix.get function index column 10 is out if bound, column size is 10"